# Picture of a Matching

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use tikz to plot this picture

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Begin here: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red,very thick](0,0)node[left]{L2}--(2,0)node[right]{F2}--(0,1)node[left]{L1}--(2,1)node[right]{F1}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One out of many ways.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {red,red,blue,blue,green!70!black,green!70!black,green!70!black}
 {\draw[color=\X] (-1,-0.7*\Y) node (L\Y) {L\Y}  (1,-0.7*\Y) node (R\Y)  {R\Y}
 (L\Y) -- (R\Y); }
 \foreach \X/\Z [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)}] in
 {1/red,3/blue,5/green!70!black,6/green!70!black}
 {\draw[color=\Z] (L\X) -- (R\Y)  (L\Y) -- (R\X);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]